# Paste onto visible cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to paste a normal column of values (unhidden) into a selection that contains hidden values. When doing this, I would like for excel to ignore the cells in between as if they were deleted. For example:

[image: 1]

```
Cells A1-A3 contain 1,2,3. Cells C3-C5 contain A,B,C
```

[image]

```
We hide row 2, so that the '2' is no longer visible.
```

[image]

```
A normal paste will result in the 'B' overwriting the hidden '2'.
```

[image]

```
This is what the solution would look like, meaning the '2' is unaffected.
```

Currently, I'm aware of the `Alt+;` functionality that selects only the visible cells, however when trying to paste in here, excel complains about the pasting area.

Can anyone think of a solution with excel basic functionality, formulas, or VBA to achieve this?

Comment: Unhide, paste then re-hide

Comment: Your "solution" screenshot doesn't match the description (there's a "B" in place of the 2)  I think you're going to need VBA for this, and will need to loop over the source range and copy cell-by-cell, depending on whether the corresponding destination row is hidden or not.

Comment: @TimWilliams - The screenshot is correct as per his requirements but excel wil never do that. VBA is the only solution.

Comment: @Tyler-Dickinson - Check this note on this link by Microsoft, it is fundamentally not allowed in Excel.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-visible-cells-only-6e3a1f01-2884-4332-b262-8b814412847e

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using VBA

It uses arrays so it doesn't copy cell formatting

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyVisiblesOnlyAndPasteOverVisiblesOnly()
    Const FROM_COL = 3
    Const TO_COL = 1
    Dim arr As Variant, vis As Variant, ub As Long, i As Long, j As Long, itm As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arr = .UsedRange.Columns(FROM_COL)
        ub = UBound(arr)
        ReDim vis(1 To ub)
        j = 1
        For i = 1 To ub     'Copy visible cells in column 3
            If Not IsError(arr(i, 1)) Then  'skip errors, empty, and hidden rows to copy
                If Len(arr(i, 1)) > 0 And .Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
                    vis(j) = arr(i, 1)
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
        ub = j - 1
        ReDim Preserve vis(1 To ub)

        If ub > 0 Then
            j = 1
            For i = 1 To ub
                While .Rows(j).Hidden = True    'skip hidden rows to paste over
                    j = j + 1
                Wend
                .Cells(j, TO_COL) = vis(i)
                j = j + 1
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Test sheet - all rows visible

[image: TestSheetAllRows]

Test sheet - only visible rows

[image: TestSheetVisibleRows]

.

Result - only visible rows

[image: ResultSheetVisibleRows]

Result - all rows

[image: ResultSheetAllRows]